# Agent Based Simulations utilizing the XBOX 360 in C#

Tags: c#, simulation, xbox360, agent-based-modeling

What is the best way to design an ABS using the XBOX 360 hardware?  Can I follow my standard developing framework methodologies such as domain driven design?  Are there frameworks out there that handle world creation and updates in C# for XBOX?  Any good resources regarding the creation of generic simulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA is your friend. It's free and you write Apps in C#.

http://creators.xna.com/en-US/

Comment: But how does it support building simulations?  Are there any frameworks out there that integrate into XNA for building agent based simulations?

Comment: XNA is a platform for creating games for the xbox 360 or windows. However you can design simulation or other applications for it, as others have done. For instance, you might be interested in http://repast.sourceforge.net/ . I don't know if it works on the xbox though...